# php sessions username/password

Tags: php, session

I'm only just starting to learn PHP and have done ok so far but I have confused myself with sessions.

If someone could have a look at my code and let me know where i have went wrong and how i can fix it that would be fantastic!

The username/password is hard coded to admin 123 as instructed.

Thanks

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>if statements</title>
</head>

PHP

<body>
Login
<form action="username.php" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="username">Enter your username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password">Enter your password</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="GO"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="GO" id="GO" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>



<html>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
If($username==”admin” && $password==”123”)

    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ;

    if ($name != 'admin' || $pass != '123')
    {
        elseif ($username === '')
            die("ERROR: Please enter the username!");

        elseif ($password === '')
            die("ERROR: Please enter the password!");

        elseif ($name == "test" && $pass == "test") {

            // authentication successful, save username in session:
            $_SESSION['user'] = 'admin';

            // redirect to index.php to welcome the logged in user:
            header('Location: index.html');
            exit;
        }
        else {
            die("ERROR: Incorrect username or password!");
        }
    }


    ?>











</body>
</html>
```

EDIT

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
If($username==”admin” && $password=="123”)

    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ;



     if ($username == "admin" && $password == "123") {

            // authentication successful, save username in session:
            $_SESSION['username'] = 'admin';
            $_SESSION['password'] = '123';

            // redirect to welcome.html to welcome the logged in user:
            header('Location: welcome.html');
            exit;
        }
        else {
            die("ERROR: Incorrect username or password!");
        }


    // no submitted data, display form:
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT AGAIN:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php


session_start();
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($username === 'admin' && $password === '123') 
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'admin';
    $_SESSION['password'] = '123';

    session_write_close();{
                  // redirect to welcome.html to welcome the logged in user:
            header('Location: welcome.html');
            exit;
    }
}


        else {
            die("ERROR: Incorrect username or password!");
        }


    // no submitted data, display form:
    ?>











</body>
</html>
```

It kind of works now, but even with wrong username/password it goes to welcome.html

Comment: how come i have gotten 2 thumbs down? i have already stated i have just started learning php

Comment: i have edited the code, maybe its a little better and i can get some help?

Comment: where is your username.php file's code?Do you use mysql database to confirm password?

Comment: thats it, there is no database or anything as i am just starting

Comment: first, please replace all those `”` symbols with normal quots `"` (the former don't have the meaning that you may think); and second, if the indented stuff after `If($username==...` is meant to be executed when the statement is true, wrap those into a curly brackets block. Retest it afterwards and clearly state what problem do you have with it (what error messages do you get, what unexpected behaviour takes place etc)

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things wrong with your code.

```
If($username==”admin” && $password==”123”)

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ;
```

You are checking if `$username` and `$password` are equal to a string before they are defined. You should first declare your variable before checking if it's equal to some string. Second, the `isset` function will check if the variable is set and then return `true` if so and `false` is it isn't. Third you are also forgetting brackets after the if statement.

You should do it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'admin123') {
       //code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

Always use session_start() before you output data.

You're assigning vars after you use them. That's the wrong order.

```
If($username==”admin” && $password=="123”)

    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ;
```

Use session_write_close() before headering:

```
$_SESSION['password'] = '123';

session_write_close();

// redirect to welcome.html to welcome the logged in user:
header('Location: welcome.html');
```

And read your code... You are the doing the same if twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example as you want in easy way.first the `session_start()`.then it will check for submitted username and password.If username is `admin` and password is `pass` than it will go to location `wherever.php`.If username and password is wrong it will echo error in `<?php echo $passError;?>`.You can `echo` variable in php by `<?php $variable=2; echo $variable;?>`.

```
   <?php
    session_start();
 $username = $password = $userError = $passError = '';
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
      if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'pass'){
        $_SESSION['login'] = true; 
    header('LOCATION:wherever.php'); //go to location after successful login.
    die();
      }
      if($username !== 'admin'){$userError = 'Invalid Username';}
      if($password !== 'password'){$passError = 'Invalid Password';}
    }
    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
       <head>
         <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
         <title>Login</title>

       </head>
    <body>
      <form name='input' action='' method='post'>
        <label for='username'></label><input type='text' value='' id='username' name='username' />
        <div class='error'><?php echo $userError;?></div>
        <label for='password'></label><input type='password' value='' id='password' name='password' />
        <div class='error'><?php echo $passError;?></div>
        <input type='submit' value='Home' name='sub' />
      </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This included in one file you can also make separate two files,one html and other php.Enter php file location in `<form action=""` if you are making two files.

Comment: thanks but that isn't what i wanted, i wanted to work through it with someone and try to understand where i went wrong. not everyone on here wants the simple answer.