# php include mysql file with redirection

Tags: php, mysql

I have quick question.

I am new to PHP and I am making a website which has a login and sign up form. I have the code worked out however I am using php include mysql.php and I am wondering if there needs to be separate ones.

What i mean by this is there is a login for regular members and a login for admin. If member is logged in then I want the redirection to go to example.com/member and if admin then example.com/admin. Is it from the MySQL file I redirect meaning i need more than 1 or is it somewhere else I would do it?

At the moment I do not want to do it all on the same page which is why i'm doing it this way.

Any guidance would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435675/php-sessions-username-password and accept an answer that solved your problem, up-voting any answers that helped you. Then, do the same here. This encourages the SO community to help more people who are new to technology. You could also answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:**
Use `header("Location: somepage.php");` to redirect based on `$_SESSION['user_type']` or SQL query at the beginning of each page. No need for separate logins.

I am assuming `mysql.php` is your database file:

**mysql.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'db', port);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "DB Error!"; exit();
}
?>
```

At the top of all pages, add something like the following. This will redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in. Lots of assumptions (integer ID, SESSION variables etc), but you get the idea:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("mysql.php");
// If not logged in, go to login
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']) {
  if($result = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT id FROM `USER` WHERE id = ? AND session_id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $session_id = session_id();
    $result -> bind_param("i", $_SESSION['uid']);
    $result -> execute();
    $result -> store_result();
    if($result -> num_rows != 1) {
      header("Location: login");
      exit();
    }
  }
  else {
    header("Location: login");
    exit();
  }
}
else {
  header("Location: login");
  exit();
}
?>
```

In the same way, you can redirect if a logged in user is an admin or member (using something like `$_SESSION['user_type']`, which is set upon login). Because you're new, here's some more code:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("mysql.php");
// If already logged in, redirect to admin or members based on session variable.
// ...
//
// If a login form has been submitted (assuming you're logging in from a POST)
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password']) {
    if($result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, user_type, password FROM `USER` WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {
      $result -> bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
      $result -> execute();
      $result -> store_result();
      if($result -> num_rows == 1) {
        $result -> bind_result($id, $username, $user_type, $bcrypted);
        $result -> fetch();
        if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $bcrypted)) {
          session_regenerate_id(); // Avoid Session Fixation Attack
          $session_id = session_id(); // Update the USER table using this
          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
          $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;
          $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
          // Log some data to your DB, login time, ip, etc
          header("Location: ".($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin' ? 'admin.php' : 'member.php'));
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
<html> ...
```

Quite a few points in there. Regenerate session IDs before actual 'login', use bcrypt for passwords, assuming you understand parameterized statements for MySQL, there's also a ternary operator in there. Don't forget a logout page:

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = False;
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

I hope at least some of this helps. There's a million things I haven't covered, but you can learn a lot from material already on the web. Good luck!